# Find different elements when comparing two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists. `X` list is bigger, `Y` list is smaller.
I want to find elements from `Y` list that are unique. Meaning: elements that are not part of any element in `X` list, but also that there are no elements from `X` that are part of them.

For example: `A A` is part of `A A B`, `AA B` is part of `AA BB` but `C BB` and `S` are not part of any element in `X`.

Also, you will see that `X` has `C A` which is a part of `CC A` in `Y`, that is not allowed so it is not in the output.

```
X = ["A A B", "A B C", "AA BB", "BB C A", "A C B", "BB C A", "X", "C A"]
Y = ["A A", "A C A", "AA B", "C BB", "S", "CC A"]
```

I have tried something like this, with different places of `else` but it does not work good:

```
for x in X:
    for y in Y:
        if x in y or y in x:
            continue
    else:
        print(y)
```

It just print `CC A` multiple times.

Requested result:

```
C BB
S
```

Comment: Your `else` is indented incorrectly; it should be indented one block more, to align with the `if`.

Comment: Of just change the `if` clause to `if x not in y and y not in x: print(y)`, then you don't need the else.

Comment: It won't work such way, it will print element multiple times then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go over each element in `Y`.
- For each one, go over each element in `X`.
- If any of them contain each other in any direction - `break`.
- Else, take the item:

```py
X = ["A A B", "A B C", "AA BB", "BB C A", "A C B", "BB C A", "X", "C A"]
Y = ["A A", "A C A", "AA B", "C BB", "S", "CC A"]

for y in Y:
    for x in X:
        if y in x or x in y:
            break
    else:
        print(y)
```

Gives:

```
C BB
S
```

This uses the [`for/else` construct](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) which means that the `else` part will only be executed if the loop executed to exhaustion, without `break`ing.

---

Or, the shorter way by using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```py
for y in Y:
    if not any(y in x or x in y for x in X):
        print(y)
```

or, by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```py
for y in Y:
    if all(y not in x and x not in y for x in X):
        print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about `len(X) * len(Y)` complexity, you can use `any`

```
X = ["A A B", "A B C", "AA BB", "BB C A", "A C B", "BB C A", "X", "C A"]
Y = ["A A", "A C A", "AA B", "C BB", "S", "CC A"]

for y_el in Y:
    if any(y_el in x_el or x_el in y_el for x_el in X):
        continue
    print(y_el)
```

Comment: This wont work, first el is not defined, second,  X list has C A and Y list has CC A, thats not allowed. Your answer prints CC A

Comment: Actually the question changed slightly... are you sure A C A is expected then? C A is a prt of A C A